# Java implementation of Authentication (HMAC) and then Descryption (AES) of a UTF8 Message (C# and Java (Android) Compatibility)

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption

I've been face rolling my keyboard all week trying to get this C# encryption class (https://gist.github.com/jbtule/4336842#file-aesthenhmac-cs) converted into java.

The problem I am running into is messages encrypted from c# will not decrypt in Java, and vise versa.

The Java class encrypts and decrypts just fine (however I have my doubts its actually doing it securely based on it not working with c#)

Here is the Crypt Class:

```
package com.hexninja.datacrypt.crypt;

import org.spongycastle.crypto.BufferedBlockCipher;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.engines.RijndaelEngine;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.io.CipherOutputStream;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.paddings.BlockCipherPadding;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.spongycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
import org.spongycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * Created by David on 11/26/2014.
 */
public final class Crypt {

// -- SpongyCastle, i choose you!
// -- ok, so a lame pokemon reference.
// -- but seriously, use this provider!
static {
    Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
}

private static final Random random = new Random();

//Preconfigured Encryption Parameters
public static final int BlockBitSize = 256;
public static final int KeyBitSize = 256;

//Preconfigured Password Key Derivation Parameters
public static final int SaltBitSize = 64;
public static final int Iterations = 3;
public static final int MinPasswordLength = 4;

private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

/// <summary>
/// Simple Encryption (AES) then Authentication (HMAC) of a UTF8 message
/// using Keys derived from a Password (PBKDF2).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="secretMessage">The secret message.</param>
/// <param name="password">The password.</param>
/// <param name="nonSecretPayload">The non secret payload.</param>
/// <returns>
/// Encrypted Message
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">password</exception>
/// <remarks>
/// Significantly less secure than using random binary keys.
/// Adds additional non secret payload for key generation parameters.
/// </remarks>
public static String SimpleEncryptWithPassword(String secretMessage, String password, byte[] nonSecretPayload)
{
    //if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(secretMessage))
    if (secretMessage.isEmpty() || secretMessage == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Secret Message Required!");
    }

    //var plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretMessage);
    //var cipherText = SimpleEncryptWithPassword(plainText, password, nonSecretPayload);
    //return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);


    byte[] plainText = null;
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    //byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretMessage);
    try {
        plainText = secretMessage.getBytes("UTF-8");
        cipherText = SimpleEncryptWithPassword(plainText, password, nonSecretPayload);
        //return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (cipherText != null) {
    //return Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return Base64.toBase64String(cipherText);
    //return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(cipherText), UTF8);
}
else
    return null;



}

/// <summary>
/// Simple Authentication (HMAC) and then Descryption (AES) of a UTF8 Message
/// using keys derived from a password (PBKDF2).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="encryptedMessage">The encrypted message.</param>
/// <param name="password">The password.</param>
/// <param name="nonSecretPayloadLength">Length of the non secret payload.</param>
/// <returns>
/// Decrypted Message
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">Encrypted Message Required!;encryptedMessage</exception>
/// <remarks>
/// Significantly less secure than using random binary keys.
/// </remarks>
public static String SimpleDecryptWithPassword(String encryptedMessage, String password, int nonSecretPayloadLength) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    //if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(encryptedMessage))
    if (encryptedMessage.isEmpty() || encryptedMessage == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Encrypted Message Required!");
    }

    byte[] cipherText = Base64.decode(encryptedMessage);
    byte[] plainText = SimpleDecryptWithPassword(cipherText, password, nonSecretPayloadLength);
    //String s = new String(plainText, "ISO-8859-1");
    //byte[] stream = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");

    return new String(plainText, "UTF8");
    //return Base64.toBase64String(plainText);
    //return plainText.toString();
}

public static byte[] SimpleEncrypt(byte[] secretMessage, byte[] cryptKey, byte[] authKey, byte[] nonSecretPayload)
    {
        //User Error Checks
        if (cryptKey == null || cryptKey.length != KeyBitSize / 8)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key needs to be " + KeyBitSize + " bit!");

        if (authKey == null || authKey.length != KeyBitSize / 8)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key needs to be " + KeyBitSize + " bit!");

        if (secretMessage == null || secretMessage.length < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Secret Message Required!");

        //non-secret payload optional
        //nonSecretPayload = nonSecretPayload ?? new byte[] { };
        if (nonSecretPayload == null) {
            nonSecretPayload = new byte[] { };
        }

        byte[] cipherText = null;
        //byte[] iv = null;

        System.out.println("SimpleEncrypt stage 1");

    try {

        System.out.println("SimpleEncrypt stage 2");

        //Grab IV from message
        byte[] ivData = new byte[BlockBitSize / 8];
        Random r = new Random(); // Note: no  seed here, ie these values are truly random
        r.nextBytes(ivData);

        // Select encryption algorithm and padding : AES with CBC and PCKS#7
        CipherParameters params = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(cryptKey), ivData);
        BlockCipherPadding padding = new PKCS7Padding();
        BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256)), padding);

        cipher.reset();
        cipher.init(true, params); // first param = encode/decode

        // -- a wannabe using statement..
        // -- c# like memorystream
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream cipherStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            // -- c# like CryptoStream
            try (CipherOutputStream cryptoStream = new CipherOutputStream(cipherStream, cipher)) {
                // -- binaryWriter like c#
                try (DataOutputStream binaryWriter = new DataOutputStream(cryptoStream)) {
                    // -- Encrypt Data
                    binaryWriter.write(secretMessage);
                }
                cipherText = cipherStream.toByteArray();
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("SimpleEncrypt stage 3");

        //Assemble encrypted message and add authentication
        try {
            System.out.println("SimpleEncrypt stage 4");
            Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            System.out.println("authKey =" + Base64.toBase64String(authKey));
            SecretKey signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(authKey, "HMACSHA256");
            System.out.println("authKey=" +  Base64.toBase64String(authKey));
            hmac.init(signingKey);
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream encryptedStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                try (DataOutputStream binaryWriter = new DataOutputStream(encryptedStream)) {
                    //Prepend non-secret payload if any
                    binaryWriter.write(nonSecretPayload);
                    //Prepend IV
                    binaryWriter.write(ivData);
                    //Write Ciphertext
                    binaryWriter.write(cipherText);
                    binaryWriter.flush();


                    System.out.println("computeByte=" +  Base64.toBase64String(encryptedStream.toByteArray()));

                    //Authenticate all data
                    //var tag = hmac.ComputeHash(encryptedStream.ToArray());
                    //hmac.init(secretKeySpecy);
                    byte[] tag = hmac.doFinal(encryptedStream.toByteArray());
                    //System.out.println("tag text=" + tag.length);
                    System.out.println("tag=" +  Base64.toBase64String(tag));
                    //Postpend tag
                    binaryWriter.write(tag);
                }
                return encryptedStream.toByteArray();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;


}

public static byte[] SimpleDecrypt(byte[] encryptedMessage, byte[] cryptKey, byte[] authKey, int nonSecretPayloadLength)
{

    //Basic Usage Error Checks
    if (cryptKey == null || cryptKey.length != KeyBitSize / 8)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("CryptKey needs to be " + KeyBitSize + " bit!");

    if (authKey == null || authKey.length != KeyBitSize / 8)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("AuthKey needs to be " + KeyBitSize + " bit!");

    if (encryptedMessage == null || encryptedMessage.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Encrypted Message Required!");


    try {
        // verify HMAC!
        Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKey signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(authKey, "HMACSHA256");
        hmac.init(signingKey);

        System.out.println("authKey=" +  Base64.toBase64String(authKey));


        // -- hmac is already 32 bytes.. I was expecting bits. (c# does bits)
        //byte[] sentTag = new byte[sha256_HMAC.getMacLength() / 8];
        byte[] sentTag = new byte[hmac.getMacLength()];




        byte[] computeByte = new byte[encryptedMessage.length - sentTag.length];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedMessage, 0, computeByte, 0, computeByte.length);

        System.out.println("computeByte=" +  Base64.toBase64String(computeByte));

        // -- fix for missing ComputeHash from c#
        //MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("HMACSHA256");
        //byte[] digest = m.digest(computeByte);
        //String hashcode = new BigInteger(1,m.digest()).toString(16);

        //System.out.println("hashcode=" +  hashcode);


        byte[] calcTag = hmac.doFinal(computeByte);
        int ivLength = (BlockBitSize / 8);

        System.out.println("calcTag=" +  Base64.toBase64String(calcTag));

        //if message length is to small just return null
        if (encryptedMessage.length < sentTag.length + nonSecretPayloadLength + ivLength)
            return null;

        System.out.println("we are past encrypted Message length");

        //Grab Sent Tag
        System.arraycopy(encryptedMessage, encryptedMessage.length - sentTag.length, sentTag, 0, sentTag.length);


        System.out.println("sentTag=" +  Base64.toBase64String(sentTag));

        //Compare Tag with constant time comparison
        int compare = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sentTag.length; i++)
            compare |= sentTag[i] ^ calcTag[i];

        System.out.println("compare =" + compare);

        //if message doesn't authenticate return null
        if (compare != 0)
            return null;



        //Grab IV from message
        byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedMessage, nonSecretPayloadLength, iv, 0, iv.length);

        System.out.println("iv=" +  Base64.toBase64String(iv));

        //iv = ivSpec.getIV();
        CipherParameters params = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(cryptKey), iv);
        BlockCipherPadding padding = new PKCS7Padding();
        BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256)), padding);

        cipher.reset();
        cipher.init(false, params);

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream plainTextStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            // -- c# like CryptoStream
            try (CipherOutputStream decrypterStream = new CipherOutputStream(plainTextStream, cipher)) {
                // -- binaryWriter like c#
                try (DataOutputStream binaryWriter = new DataOutputStream(decrypterStream)) {
                    // -- Encrypt Data
                    //Decrypt Cipher Text from Message
                    binaryWriter.write(
                            encryptedMessage,
                            nonSecretPayloadLength + iv.length,
                            encryptedMessage.length - nonSecretPayloadLength - iv.length - sentTag.length
                    );
                }
                //Return Plain Text
                //decrypterStream.flush();

            } finally {
                return plainTextStream.toByteArray();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static byte[] SimpleEncryptWithPassword(byte[] secretMessage, String password, byte[] nonSecretPayload) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    if (nonSecretPayload == null) {
        nonSecretPayload = new byte[] { };
    }

    //User Error Checks
    if (password.isEmpty() || password == null || password.length() < MinPasswordLength) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must have a password of at least "+MinPasswordLength+" characters!");
    }

    if (secretMessage == null || secretMessage.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Secret Message Required!");

    byte[] payload = new byte[((SaltBitSize / 8) * 2) + nonSecretPayload.length];

    System.arraycopy(nonSecretPayload, 0, payload, 0, nonSecretPayload.length);
    //Array.Copy(nonSecretPayload, payload, nonSecretPayload.Length);
    int payloadIndex = nonSecretPayload.length;

    byte[] cryptKey = null;
    byte[] authKey = null;

    try {

        Random r = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[SaltBitSize / 8];
        r.nextBytes(salt);


        Rfc2898DeriveBytes generator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, Iterations);
        //Generate Keys
        cryptKey = generator.getBytes(KeyBitSize / 8);

        //Create Non Secret Payload
        System.arraycopy(salt, 0, payload, payloadIndex, salt.length);
        //System.arraycopy(nonSecretPayload, 0, payload, 0, nonSecretPayload.length);
        payloadIndex += salt.length;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        Random r = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = new byte[SaltBitSize / 8];
        r.nextBytes(salt);

        Rfc2898DeriveBytes generator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, Iterations);
        //Generate Keys
        authKey = generator.getBytes(KeyBitSize / 8);

        //Create Non Secret Payload
        System.arraycopy(salt, 0, payload, payloadIndex, salt.length);
        //System.arraycopy(nonSecretPayload, 0, payload, 0, nonSecretPayload.length);
        payloadIndex += salt.length;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("cryptKey=" +  Base64.toBase64String(cryptKey));
    System.out.println("authKey=" + Base64.toBase64String(authKey));

    return SimpleEncrypt(secretMessage, cryptKey, authKey, payload);
}

public static byte[] SimpleDecryptWithPassword(byte[] encryptedMessage, String password, int nonSecretPayloadLength) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    //User Error Checks
    if (password.isEmpty() || password == null || password.length() < MinPasswordLength) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must have a password of at least "+MinPasswordLength+" characters!");
    }

    if (encryptedMessage == null || encryptedMessage.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Encrypted Message Required!");

    byte[] cryptSalt = new byte[SaltBitSize / 8];
    byte[] authSalt = new byte[SaltBitSize / 8];

    //Grab Salt from Non-Secret Payload
    System.arraycopy(encryptedMessage, nonSecretPayloadLength, cryptSalt, 0, cryptSalt.length);
    System.arraycopy(encryptedMessage, nonSecretPayloadLength + cryptSalt.length, authSalt, 0, authSalt.length);

    System.out.println("cryptSalt=" + Base64.toBase64String(cryptSalt));
    System.out.println("authSalt=" + Base64.toBase64String(authSalt));


    Rfc2898DeriveBytes generator = null;
    try {
        generator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, cryptSalt, Iterations);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] cryptKey = generator.getBytes(KeyBitSize / 8);

    try {
        generator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, authSalt, Iterations);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] authKey = generator.getBytes(KeyBitSize / 8);

    //byte[] cryptKey = Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, cryptSalt, Iterations);
    //byte[] authKey = Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, authSalt, Iterations);

    System.out.println("cryptKey=" +  Base64.toBase64String(cryptKey));
    System.out.println("authKey=" + Base64.toBase64String(authKey));

    return SimpleDecrypt(encryptedMessage, cryptKey, authKey, cryptSalt.length + authSalt.length + nonSecretPayloadLength);
}

/*
private static byte[] Rfc2898DeriveBytes(String password, byte[] salt, int iterations) throws GeneralSecurityException {

    // get raw key from password and salt
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, Iterations, SaltBitSize);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC");
    SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec).getEncoded(), "HMACSHA256");
    byte[] rawKeyData = secretKey.getEncoded();

    return rawKeyData;
}
*/

}
```

I know its quite large.. here is the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class

```
package com.hexninja.datacrypt.crypt;

/**
 * Created by David on 12/2/2014.
 */
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * RFC 2898 password derivation compatible with .NET Rfc2898DeriveBytes class.
 */
public class Rfc2898DeriveBytes {

private Mac _hmacSha1;
private byte[] _salt;
private int _iterationCount;

private byte[] _buffer = new byte[20];
private int _bufferStartIndex = 0;
private int _bufferEndIndex = 0;
private int _block = 1;


/**
 * Creates new instance.
 * @param password The password used to derive the key.
 * @param salt The key salt used to derive the key.
 * @param iterations The number of iterations for the operation.
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException HmacSHA1 algorithm cannot be found.
 * @throws InvalidKeyException Salt must be 8 bytes or more. -or- Password cannot be null.
 */
public Rfc2898DeriveBytes(byte[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    if ((salt == null) || (salt.length < 8)) { throw new InvalidKeyException("Salt must be 8 bytes or more."); }
    if (password == null) { throw new InvalidKeyException("Password cannot be null."); }
    this._salt = salt;
    this._iterationCount = iterations;
    this._hmacSha1 = Mac.getInstance("HMACSHA256");
    this._hmacSha1.init(new SecretKeySpec(password, "HMACSHA256"));
}

/**
 * Creates new instance.
 * @param password The password used to derive the key.
 * @param salt The key salt used to derive the key.
 * @param iterations The number of iterations for the operation.
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException HmacSHA1 algorithm cannot be found.
 * @throws InvalidKeyException Salt must be 8 bytes or more. -or- Password cannot be null.
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException UTF-8 encoding is not supported.
 */
public Rfc2898DeriveBytes(String password, byte[] salt, int iterations) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException  {
    this(password.getBytes("UTF8"), salt, iterations);
}

/**
 * Creates new instance.
 * @param password The password used to derive the key.
 * @param salt The key salt used to derive the key.
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException HmacSHA1 algorithm cannot be found.
 * @throws InvalidKeyException Salt must be 8 bytes or more. -or- Password cannot be null.
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException UTF-8 encoding is not supported.
 */
public Rfc2898DeriveBytes(String password, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    this(password, salt, 0x3e8);
}


/**
 * Returns a pseudo-random key from a password, salt and iteration count.
 * @param count Number of bytes to return.
 * @return Byte array.
 */
public byte[] getBytes(int count) {
    byte[] result = new byte[count];
    int resultOffset = 0;
    int bufferCount = this._bufferEndIndex - this._bufferStartIndex;

    if (bufferCount > 0) { //if there is some data in buffer
        if (count < bufferCount) { //if there is enough data in buffer
            System.arraycopy(this._buffer, this._bufferStartIndex, result, 0, count);
            this._bufferStartIndex += count;
            return result;
        }
        System.arraycopy(this._buffer, this._bufferStartIndex, result, 0, bufferCount);
        this._bufferStartIndex = this._bufferEndIndex = 0;
        resultOffset += bufferCount;
    }

    while (resultOffset < count) {
        int needCount = count - resultOffset;
        this._buffer = this.func();
        if (needCount > 20) { //we one (or more) additional passes
            System.arraycopy(this._buffer, 0, result, resultOffset, 20);
            resultOffset += 20;
        } else {
            System.arraycopy(this._buffer, 0, result, resultOffset, needCount);
            this._bufferStartIndex = needCount;
            this._bufferEndIndex = 20;
            return result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


private byte[] func() {
    this._hmacSha1.update(this._salt, 0, this._salt.length);
    byte[] tempHash = this._hmacSha1.doFinal(getBytesFromInt(this._block));

    this._hmacSha1.reset();
    byte[] finalHash = tempHash;
    for (int i = 2; 5i <= this._iterationCount; i++) {
        tempHash = this._hmacSha1.doFinal(tempHash);
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            finalHash[j] = (byte)(finalHash[j] ^ tempHash[j]);
        }
    }
    if (this._block == 2147483647) {
        this._block = -2147483648;
    } else {
        this._block += 1;
    }

    return finalHash;
}

private static byte[] getBytesFromInt(int i) {
    return new byte[] { (byte)(i >>> 24), (byte)(i >>> 16), (byte)(i >>> 8), (byte)i };
}

}
```

And here is the implementation

```
String encryptedText = Crypt.SimpleEncryptWithPassword("My string to encrypt", "VeryHardPassword", null);
System.out.println("encrypted text=" + encryptedText);
System.out.println("decrypted text=" + Crypt.SimpleDecryptWithPassword(encryptedText, "VeryHardPassword", 0));
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of code. Note that PBKDF2 (Rfc2898DeriveBytes) functionality should already been present in Java (although it is only compatible for ASCII characters). If you have already verified that the keys are correct, then it seems you are using a **block** size of 256 bits in Java vs 128 bit (i.e. AES) in the C# code of jbtule.

Comment: I forgot to mention I modified the c# implementation a little bit (had deprication and other things) as well as 256 bit.

The cryptKey and authKey are different (Java/C#), i think the error is in Rfc2898DeriveBytes, so at least now i know where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: drop the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class.. use this function to DeriveBytes..

```
private static byte[] Rfc2898DeriveBytes(String password, byte[] salt, int iterations) throws GeneralSecurityException {

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, Iterations, 256);
    Key secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
    byte[] rawKeyData = secretKey.getEncoded();
    return rawKeyData;
}
```

There are also some changes in the crypt class referring to Rfc2898DeriveBytes where applicable.

```
byte[] cryptKey = Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, cryptSalt, Iterations);
byte[] authKey = Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, authSalt, Iterations);
```

With these changes, it will accept any c# encrypt to java decrypt as well as java encrypt to c# decrypt!

Makes me happy :)